# Combobox select item in dropdown list C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have an combobox poppulated with items from a database table.
 When I change the text i repopulate the combobox with items from the database table.

But when I enter text and the list with suggestions opens no item in de list is selected. 
And i want a item to be selected so when you press enter that it becomes the selected item.

This is a winforms application.

Thanks.

```
 cbxNaam.Items.Clear();
 string query = "SELECT bedr_naam FROM tblbedrijf WHERE bedr_naam LIKE '%" + cbxNaam.Text + "%'";
 string[] bedrijfsnamen = Functions.DataTableToArray(Global.db.Select(query));
 cbxNaam.Items.AddRange(bedrijfsnamen);
 cbxNaam.Select(cbxNaam.Text.Length + 1, 0);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Why don't you use autocompletion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to select an item in the list - it looks like you are trying to select some text in an item.

piecing together some info from your other comments it looks like you want to essentially do a wildcard match on the text in the dropdown list, to do this you will need to modify behaviour of the handler for the text changed event/method, either derive from combobox and override it or ad an event listener on your instance.

you can then do a search on the data in your array - something like

```
private void cbxNaam_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var matchingStrings = bedrijfsnamen.Where(s => s.Contains(cbxNaam.Text));
     cbxNaam.SelectedItem = matchingStrings[0];
}
```

you will need to be a little careful of multiple matching items etc.

Comment: this will select the combobox item and i want it to select an item in the dropdown list of the droplist

Comment: see update to text above - I think this is more what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **WINFORMS**,

You have to use [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource.aspx) set to `AutoCompleteMode.Append` and [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource.aspx) set to `AutoCompleteSource.ListItems`

Please check this answer [ComboBox AutoComplete Custom Capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776466/1547740)

Comment: But when i use this it only autocompletes from the start of the string. So when i enter a partial string of the name that is halfway in the string it does not work

Comment: Sorry, windows combo box AutoComplete [match with prefix only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314248/1547740)... So you have to write your custom control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you good, sorry if not! Here is my answer:

If you want for your comboBox to be populated when you write in you comboBox you need to set its properties:

AutoCompleteMode to **Append**
and
AutoCompleteSource to **ListItems**

on Enter your item will be selected.

Hope I helped you? Rock On!!!:-)