# AutoComplete from any position

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

For example I have this comboBox items: `Advance Math`, `Science`, `English`, `History of America`.
How to have AutoComplete from any position? For example I type 'Mat', the `Advance Math` should show in the suggestion. Or type 'gli', the `English` should show in the suggestion.

Comment: It seems like the other option you have is performing a quite relevant custom development affecting the control (here you have a question asking something on these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776390/combobox-autocomplete-custom-capabilities). Apparently there is more information on WPF codes doing this than C# ones. But nothing easy anyway.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694720/combobox-autocomplete-on-substring